# Ordenar uma lista de objetos em Dart

Tags: lista, flutter, dart

sou iniciante no mundo da programação e estou tendo dificuldades para retornar uma lista de objetos em ordem crescente de um atributo chamado "numero"
o a lista é :

```
String nome
int numero
 

    List<Pessoas> rankingTest(List<Pessoas> list) {
  return list.sort((a,b)=> a.numero!.compareTo(b.numero!));
```

Estou tentando retornar assim, mas é do tipo Void e não consigo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: É erro de uso, a função .sort() não retorna a array, retorna *void*, o método .sort() altera o array original, após executar basta retornar a própria `list` no return, você também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para trabalhar com ordenação de listas é básicamente o que você fez. O único problema seu é tentar retornar a função *sort()*, que por sua vez não possuí retorno de valores.

Para ordenar uma lista basta fazer:

```
class Pessoa {
  Pessoa(this.nome, this.numero);
  String nome;
  int numero;
}

void main() {
  final pessoas = <Pessoa>[
    Pessoa("Nome 1", 1),
    Pessoa("Nome 3", 3),
    Pessoa("Nome 2", 2),
  ];

  // Função que ordena a lista
  List<Pessoa> ordernarLista(List<Pessoa> lista) {
    List<Pessoa> ordernado = lista.toList();
    ordernado.sort((a, b) => a.numero.compareTo(b.numero));
    return ordernado;
  }
  
  // Exibir lista ordenada
  ordernarLista(pessoas).forEach((pessoa) => print(pessoa.nome));
}
```

*Se quiser ler um pouco mais sobre [como ordenar uma lista em Dart](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html).*

Você pode testar meu exemplo aqui no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id), basta copiar e colar.

#### Explicação

A função *sort()* é apenas uma função auxiliar (Chamada de *Extensions*) que vai ordenar a lista à qual você chamou a função e já organizar diretamente na instância (variável) que tu chamou a função.
Por isso ela retorna um *Void*, ou nulo para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Obrigado Matheus! consegui resolver meu problema com seu auxilio, só mais uma duvida, estava brincando no dartpad aqui tentando reverter a lista, e não consegui! poderia me dar mais essa ajuda?

Comment: Para reverter a lista você pode fazer `return ordenado.reversed` ou apenas trocar a ordem do _sort()_, ficando assim `sort((a, b) => b.numero.compareTo(a.numero))`